# Dplyr: How can i calculate proportional means?

Tags: r

Say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", 
"Banana", "Banana"), Status = c("Eaten", "Eaten", "Eaten", "Trashed", 
"Eaten", "Trashed", "Eaten", "Eaten", "Trashed", "Eaten", "Eaten", 
"Trashed", "Trashed")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

By just looking at it, we see that Apples have the highest count of `Trashed`, but this is because it also appears most frequently. On the other hand, we see that Banana has 100% occurrences of it being `Trashed`.

Which function would allow me to see which fruit type is proportionally trashed the most? For example, the output should be:
Banana-100% trashed
Orange-0% trashed
Apple-30% trashed

I would also like to create a visualization for this as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the column to logical and do a group by `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Fruit) %>%
   summarise(TrashPerc = 100 * mean(Status == "Trashed"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Fruit  TrashPerc
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Apple         30
2 Banana       100
3 Orange         0
```

---

If we need to get bar plot

```
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
    group_by(Fruit) %>%
    summarise(TrashPerc = 100 * mean(Status == "Trashed")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Fruit, y = TrashPerc)) + 
      geom_col()
```

Answer (score 3):

The bare-bones base-r solution is `tapply` for the calculation, and `barplot` for the plot:

```
out <- tapply(df$Status == "Trashed", df$Fruit, mean) * 100
barplot(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve your problem using the built-in functions `table` and `proportions` to get the relative frequency, and `barplot` for the plot.

```
barplot(proportions(table(df), "Fruit")[, "Trashed"] * 100)
```

[image]